# How to hide numbers in custom sections and paragraphs

Tags: macros, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to customize my own sections but I can't figure out how to hide the numbers for each section. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{18pt}{21.6}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8}\selectfont}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\paragraph}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4}\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4}\itshape\flushleft}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\begin{document}    
    
    \section{section}
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words 
    
    \subsection{subsection}
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words 
    
    \subsubsection{subsubsection}
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words \
    
    \paragraph{paragraph}
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words 
    
    \subparagraph{subparagraph}
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words 
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\section*` ?

Comment: Use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`  if  you want them listed in the table of contents (without numbers).

Comment: I can't use \section* for custom sections unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8}\selectfont\bfseries}{}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8}\selectfont}{}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\paragraph}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4}\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4}\itshape\flushleft}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}```
````